# Using an input field with onBlur and a value from state blocks input in Reactjs JSX?

Tags: reactjs

I've made a small fiddle to show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/4TpnG/582/
When you have an input box with onBlur attached to it, and an initial value from state, input from the keyboard is blocked. When onChange is attached, it's working correctly. Why is this happening and how can this be solved? I would have expected it to accept the characters you type and update the state onBlur.

```js
var Test = React.createClass({

      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          value: "hallo"
        };
      },

      render: function() {
          return ( < form >
            < div >
            Onchange: < input type = "text"
            value = {
              this.state.value
            }
            onChange = {
              this.handleChange
            }
            /><br/ >
            Onblur: < input type = "text"
            value = {
              this.state.value
            }
            onBlur = {
              this.handleChange
            }
            />
      </div >
            < /form>
    );
  },
  handleChange: function(e){
      this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<Test/ > , document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.2/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.2/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `value` attribute ties the value of the input to that state, and if the user changes the value then the state and the input value is no longer tied to each other. So React stops that from happening.

You probably want to use the `defaultValue` attribute instead.

If you want to use the `value` attribute you need the `onChange` to sync it with the component state. This because the component can re-render at any time, and if the value is out of sync with the state that would render an old value.

Comment: Cool thanks! It works with the 'defaultValue' attribute, that is probably what you meant.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm on mobile and didn't look that up, I'll change the answer.